# Jquery post dynamic form

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of codes. It will generate multiple form dynamically. I would like to ask how to write to Jquery code to post only selected form. The $day actually come from database, to make it simple I just assigned it to 6 here.

php

```
<?php

$day = 6;

for($i=1; $i<= $day ;$i++){

    echo "<div class='item'>";
    echo "<form class='itineraryForm' id='itineraryForm$i'  method = 'post'>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Time</th>";
    echo "<th>Activities</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<input type='text' class='i_field' name='time[]' value='' />";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<input type='text' class='i_field' name='activities[]' value='' />";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "<input type='image' id='i_save_btn' src='img/save.png' value='SAVE' align='right'/>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

js

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("#i_save_btn").click( function(e){
        $.post('inc/process.php', $(".itineraryForm").serialize(), function(data) {});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code .

it is call `Event Delegation`

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

-> use `i_save_btn` as class. is always should be unique.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click',".i_save_btn",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('inc/process.php', $(this).parents('form').serialize(), function(data) {});
   });
});
```

Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/kvj3nokq/1/)

Comment: how to make i_save_btn unique? also I would only want the particular form  that are clicked to be serialize and not all the form.

Comment: use can use  `i_save_btn` as class name and this code will get data from clicked button form `$(this).parents('form').serialize()`

Comment: @user4815740  i have added demo in my answer. please check